# Make Banlist in a single embed

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

```
@client.command(aliases=['bl', 'bans', 'banslog', 'banslogs', 'banlog'])
async def banlogs(ctx):
    guild = ctx.guild

    bans = await guild.bans()
    for ban in bans:
        # await ctx.send(ban)
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Ban Logs", colour=discord.Color.red())
        embed.add_field(name="Name: ", value=f"{ban.user}")
        embed.add_field(name="Is_bot?", value=f"{ban.user.bot}")
        # embed.add_field(name="User Id: ", value=f"{ban.user.User Id}")
        embed.add_field(name="Reason: ", value=f"{ban.reason}")        
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

The code works and everything is fine but it keeps sending embed of banned users, I wanna make it to send one embed so it can be a list instead of embeds depending on how many users were banned.

Comment: It is because you have the embed in the `for`-loop. Simply send it after the `for`-loop is over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
@client.command(aliases=['bl', 'bans', 'banslog', 'banslogs', 'banlog'])
async def banlogs(ctx):
    guild = ctx.guild
    bans = await guild.bans()
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Ban Logs", colour=discord.Color.red())
    for ban in bans:
        embed.add_field(name=f"Name: ", value=f"{ban.user}")
        embed.add_field(name="Is_bot?", value=f"{ban.user.bot}")
        embed.add_field(name="Reason: ", value=f"{ban.reason}")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

as the comment above said you need to send the embed after the loop but you also have to create the embed outside of the loop otherwise it would just make new embeds and overwrite them so at the end you would just get the last ban in the embed

Comment: Tysm but do you know how to check who banned the user like Banned By who?

Comment: without looking at the [audit log](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=bans#audit-log-data) you cant